# which observer to call while removing item from cart and empty cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, event-observer, shopping-cart, bundled-product

I want to get the product SKU while removing it from the cart or when emptying the cart.

Answer (score 7):

Besides the controller `pre|post` dispatch events that don't do you much good, though you can still use them `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_delete` and `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_delete`, you can use this one 
`sales_quote_remove_item`.

You can get the sku like this:

```
public function deleteItem($observer) 
{
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    $sku = $item->getSku();
    //do something with $sku
}
```

For the empty cart action you will have to use the general controller event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_updatePost`.
And you can get the skus like this:

```
public function emptyCart($observer) 
{
    $action = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('update_cart_action');
    if ($action == 'empty_cart') {
        $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $skus = array();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $skus[] = $item->getSku();
        }
        //do something with $skus
    } 
}
```