# Products having associated crossell products should be removed if the main product is removed in magento2.1.7

Tags: magento2, cross-sells, associated-products

Products having associated crossell products should also be removed if i remove the main products in magento2.1.7 see my screenshot below..[image]

Here the flower is the main product(ie,simple product) and the teddy bear is its associated crossell product..if i remove the flower its associated crossell product ie, teddybear should also be removed automatically..plz someone guide me on this where to apply the logic

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic logic how it can be done-

You need to create an observer on `remove item from cart` event.

then in this observer you need to **get all existing cart items** and **associated cross-sell products of that item** and them **compare** them.

**For matched products, you need to remove them from cart too.**

I hope you know already how to create observer.

Check below link for event observer on cart item remove-

> [which observer to call while removing item from cart and empty cart?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/129885/which-observer-to-call-while-removing-item-from-cart-and-empty-cart)

Comment: okay sure i wil check it

Comment: ok ..please comment if you need help.